# group() id's with data difference of 1Month between entries within group

Tags: r

I am looking for a straight forward way to :
 First group ID's -> from the group only pick up the id with date difference of atleast 1 months i.e the entries with 1 Month date difference

```
ID              DATE        
A15217177635833 25-08-2018  
A15217177635833 28-06-2018   
A15217177635833 05-05-2018   
A15217177635833 30-05-2019   
F15039820795577 22-08-2017   
F15039820795577 15-06-2017   
F15039820795577 15-08-2018   
F15039820795577 25-08-2018   
F15039820795577 15-08-2018
```

Expected output:

```
 ID              DATE 
 A15217177635833 05-05-2018 
 A15217177635833 28-06-2018 (its 1 Month ahead from 05-05-2018)
 A15217177635833 25-08-2018 
 A15217177635833 30-05-2019
 F15039820795577 15-06-2017  
 F15039820795577 22-08-2017  
 F15039820795577 15-08-2018
```

I am looking to achieve this by group by and filter(dplyr) or apply() family but any other way will also be fine.

Comment: 1 month ahead from which date ? Why is `25-08-2018` selected ?

Comment: @Ronak A15217177635833 25-08-2018 is selected because it is 1 or more moth ahead of last id entry in the result data.

Comment: @chinsoon12 my apologies, yes it must be selected(i missed year) :). I am editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can convert `DATE` to date object, `arrange` it by `ID` and `DATE` and select enteries which are more than a month apart from the previous entry.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  arrange(ID, DATE) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(DATE > lag(DATE, default = TRUE) + months(1))

#  ID              DATE      
#  <fct>           <date>    
#1 A15217177635833 2018-05-05
#2 A15217177635833 2018-06-28
#3 A15217177635833 2018-08-25
#4 A15217177635833 2019-05-30
#5 F15039820795577 2017-06-15
#6 F15039820795577 2017-08-22
#7 F15039820795577 2018-08-15
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A15217177635833", "F15039820795577"), class = "factor"), 
DATE = structure(c(5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("05-05-2018", 
"15-06-2017", "15-08-2018", "22-08-2017", "25-08-2018", "28-06-2018", 
"30-05-2019"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R, "month" defined as (days in year/12):

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x){

        x <- x[order(x$DATE),]

        x$date_diff <- c(0, diff(x$DATE, n = 1))

        x[c(TRUE, x$date_diff[2:nrow(x)] > (365/12)),

          names(x) != "date_diff"]

      }

    )

  ),
row.names = NULL
)
```